# EXCEL: IF value for multiple cells

Tags: string, microsoft-excel

I have a 3 columns, some of which have countries in them like so

```
I                    J                    K
--------------       -----------------    ----------------
Denmark          
Finland
London               United Kingdom
123 street           London               United Kingdom
```

The problem is that i want to add the countries into a single cell instead of having them in multiple cells

```
L
------------
Denmark
Finland
United Kingdom
United Kingdom
```

I Have tried

```
=IF(OR(AND(J1=" United Kingdom","United Kingdom",""),AND(K1=" United Kingdom","United Kingdom",""),AND(L1=" United Kingdom","United Kingdom",""),AND(I1=" United Kingdom","United Kingdom","")),"Correct","Wrong")
```

and

```
=IF(OR(J1=" United Kingdom","United Kingdom",""),OR(K1=" United Kingdom","United Kingdom",""),OR(L1=" United Kingdom","United Kingdom",""),OR(I1=" United Kingdom","United Kingdom","")),"Correct","Wrong")
```

but this gives me an error

Does anybody know why this is not working or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (in cell `L1`)

```
=IF($K1<>"", $K1, IF($J1<>"", $J1, IF($I1<>"", $I1, "Not Provided")))
```

Have not tested this but should work.

***Edit***

based on the example you gave i assumed that column K would either be blank or a country. If it can contain spaces then try

`=IF(TRIM($K1)<>"", $K1, IF(TRIM($J1)<>"", $J1, IF(TRIM($I1)<>"", $I1, "Not Provided")))`

instead.

Comment: this just seems to print out what ever is in cell 'K', it does not  seem to be comparing cell 'K' at all

Comment: based on the example you gave i assumed that column `K` would either be blank or a country. If it can contain spaces then try
`=IF(TRIM($K1)<>"", $K1, IF(TRIM($J1)<>"", $J1, IF(TRIM($I1)<>"", $I1, "Not Provided")))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually solved the problem using the following formula

```
=IF(OR(OR(TRIM(J1)="United Kingdom"),OR(TRIM(K1)="United Kingdom"),OR(TRIM(L1)="United Kingdom"),OR(TRIM(I1)="United Kingdom")),"Correct","Wrong")
```

Comment: This solution only works for one country, you have many in your example. The solution provided by @mtariq is much more effective. Have you tried using trim() as he suggested in his comments?

Comment: also trim(" United Kingdom") returns "United Kingdom", it is more robust than hard coding the leading space. What if a bug causes two leading spaces, or a trailing space?

Comment: yes i have tried @mtariq but this way does not work, i know this way only works for 1 country but i only have 7 countries so i done this in 7 different columns and concatenated the columns then after and it worked find

Comment: Then rather create a list of your seven countries and make your function check in that list. I have no doubt that you can make @mtariq's method work though unless your issue is that the country is not always the last field (which is not demonstrated in your example)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to your solution:

Create a list of your seven countries and create a [dynamic named range](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm) of this list. Let's say you named it `CountryList`. You could keep this list on a hidden worksheet if need be. Using a dynamic named range just means you can add a new country to the list without having to adjust any of the formulae

Now in your final column put the formula

use the formula with all the `OR()` and `TRIM()` that you posted but instead of `TRIM(J1)="United Kingdom"` rather use `ISERROR(MATCH(J1, CountryList, 0 ))` to test if the cell matches something in your range and instead of `"Correct"` use `INDEX(CountryList, MATCH(J1, CountryList))` to extract the name from the list

So putting it all together:

```
=IF(OR(OR(ISERROR(MATCH(J1, CountryList, 0 ))),OR(ISERROR(MATCH(K1, CountryList, 0 ))),OR(ISERROR(MATCH(L1, CountryList, 0 ))),OR(ISERROR(MATCH(I1, CountryList, 0 )))),INDEX(CountryList, MATCH(J1, CountryList)),"Wrong")
```